# get data-attribute of selection datalist item

Tags: jquery

I have this datalist:

```
<input list="kundenliste" id="inputKundenliste">
<datalist id="kundenliste">
   <option data-info="MyInfo1">ABC</option>
   <option data-info="MyInfo2">CDE</option>
</datalist>
```

I would like to get the data-info attribute of the selected option with jQuery.
How can I get this ?
I tried this:

```
$("#inputKundenliste").change(function() {
   console.log($(this).data());
});
```

Output:

```
{ }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this code work:

```
$("#inputKundenliste").change(function() {
var elementValue = $(this).val();
  console.log($('#kundenliste').find(`option:contains(${elementValue})`).data());
});
```